# Get matrix from a pandas Series with desired shape

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large Series called s and I want to turn this into a matrix. The series repeats - so i want each set of unique values to be one row. Here's an example, s =

```
weights 
    10 
     5 
    15 
     6 
    10 
     5 
    15 
     6 
    10 
     5 
    15 
     6
```

And I want to get this matrix:

```
 [10, 5, 15, 6, 
  10, 5, 15, 6, 
  10, 5, 15, 6]
```

When I used .as_matrix() I get the wrong shape. I.E.

```
weights.as_matrix() 
> [10, 5, 15, 6, 10, 5, 15, 6, 10, 5, 15, 6,]
```

which has shape (12,)

For a very long series (which I don't know the exact shape of other than each row should have 4), how can I achieve the matrix in my example above?

Answer (score 3):

Using `reshape()`:

```
In [143]: df.as_matrix().reshape(-1,4)
Out[143]:
array([[10,  5, 15,  6],
       [10,  5, 15,  6],
       [10,  5, 15,  6]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: use `reshape(-1, 4)`

Comment: I always want the matrix to have 4 entries per row - sorry for the confusion, worded the above comment badly ^^ @chrisz

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if you write your answer as an answer below i will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to @chrisz answer, but uses `ser.values` instead of `.as_matrix()` to be more clear about what's happening.

```
ser = pd.Series([10, 5, 15, 6, 10, 5, 15, 6, 10, 5, 15, 6])

ser.values.reshape((-1, 4))
```

Output:

```
[[10  5 15  6]
 [10  5 15  6]
 [10  5 15  6]]
```